# Sort ISO 8601 dates forward or backwards

Tags: sorting, language-agnostic, iso8601

I have an array of dates in ISO8601 format and need to sort them. Does anyone have a suggestion for an algorithm that would work? I don't think they will sort as strings unless I'm much mistaken, so I assume they have to be broken down into their component parts?

Can someone post an algorithm, preferably language agnostic, but VB or C# example would work as long as it just uses strings and integers and no functions that are built-in to the language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you're mixing formats.

Within any specific format, like `yyyy-mm-dd` or `yyyy-Www-d`, ISO 8601 is built to sort lexicographically (other than negative years).

From the [ISO 8601 wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

> Date and time values are organised from the most to the least significant: year, month (or week), day, hour, minute, second, and fraction of second. The lexicographical order of the representation thus corresponds to chronological order, except for date representations involving negative years. This allows dates to be naturally sorted by, for example, file systems.

That means that string sorting should work okay.

It's only if you *mix* formats will that not work. If that's the case, you'll need to convert to a specific format before comparing. By that, I mean something like converting all formats into `yyyy-mm-dd` before comparison and then back afterwards if desired.

For example, if you have the input data:

```
2010-03-01
2010-W01-1
```

you could first change them all to:

```
2010-03-01:2010-03-01
2010-01-04:2010-W01-1
```

(prefixing the actual data with a specific form) then sort that. Once sorted, you then go back and strip off everything up to the first `:` character in each element, which will recover the original form.

Not necessarily the most efficient way but you'll need to do *something* like that if you want to preserve the original form. If that's not an issue, simply convert them to the specific form once and leave them like that.

Answer (score 14):

> I don't think they will sort as strings unless I'm much mistaken,

You *are* much mistaken :-). They will sort as strings<sup>†</sup>. That's one of the major plus points of ISO 8601 over other date formats.

See point 1:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles

> ... The lexicographical order of the representation thus corresponds to chronological order...

<sup>†</sup> <sub>as long as you aren't dealing with negative years, you are using the same timezone and you are using the same subformat i.e. you don't mix month based and week based (thanks to @paxdiablo and @whiskeysierra for pointing these out)</sub>

Comment: Nice by design BUT still much slower than sorting on unix epoch millis or sec if you have many dates

Comment: Timezones would also screw the order, wouldn't they?

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Sorting on strings is likely as quick as converting + sorting on numbers, depending on the context. If this is in a database then you should probably use the database's date type anyway, and let it handle the problem. Also no one said that speed was an issue here.

Comment: @rjmunro of course converting is costly, if you can avoid converting in the first place you can have better performance using low level millis dates, I just want to say that ISO8601 is nice but not always appropriate