# Pig 3rd party UDF clarification

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to PIG. From the pig wiki page i got to know that there is piggybank udf and another useful collection DataFu from Linkedin. Also i come to know that from Pig 0.8 the piggybank is part of apache Pig's builtin udfs.

but.. I think most of the piggybank UDFs are not documented in Apache Pig. Like StringConcat.

I am looking some date formatting UDFs which wil convert datetime to String like FormatDate.
I am not sure we have these UDF's already in pig/piggybank as i could not find it in documentation.

Also, are there any other 3rd party udfs java/python available. Please list those.

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your specific use case for string/date formatting? ie "I have a field with a unix epoch value and want to convert it to 'YYYY-MM-DD' format".

Comment: My primary question was to know about popular UDFs collections like DataFu for instance and also looks like most of the udfs from piggybank which are now part of Apache Pig API but not documented in Apache website. How to access docs for those UDFs. Example StringConcat, COUNT_STAR etc. I might be missing something here. Just want to confirm and know if there is any way to access to all availavle UDfs. Lastly, i am looking for CHARARRAY fields which is a date representation (say yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss) to convert into DateTime type or to extract year, date, month, hours etc.

Comment: I am looking for handy Date Util UDFs in general. My requirement is very broad. Looking for more information on already available UDFs.

Comment: For what it's worth, StringConcat is not "meant" to be called directly - it says "This method should never be used directly, use {@link CONCAT}." in the JavaDoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's a few questions here.  I'll try to cover them all.

***PiggyBank Docs***

There (sadly) is no user manually for piggybank UDF's that explains how to use each of them from within a pigscript.  However, the Pig javadoc includes information for each java cass implementing the UDFs in piggy bank (scroll down to "contrib: Piggybank"):

- http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/overview-summary.html
- http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/overview-summary.html
- http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/overview-summary.html

***String to DateTime***

(assuming pig < 0.11)

To convert a string containing time like information, you'll want to use the [CustomFormatToISO](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/convert/CustomFormatToISO.html) UDF.  This takes your chararray with data information and a datetime format specification and converts it into an ISO datetime format.  Once in this format, there are several Piggybank functions that operate on ISO formatted time:

- http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/truncate/package-summary.html
- http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/diff/package-summary.html

Note also that ISO formatted strings comparisons result in date sorting.  This means you can apply comparison and sort operations on them, and they will behave as if they are time aware.  For more background see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576911/9940

If you're using 0.11 plus you can use the built in ToDate() function: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#to-date