# how to convert UTC time to IST using pig

Tags: date, hadoop, apache-pig

I have a machine data comes into hdfs as below , the 8th field is UTC time(060037) , i need to convert it into IST and make the time format as hh:mm:ss using pig

```
VTS,01,0097,9739965515,NM,GP,20,060037,V,0000.0000,N,00000.0000,E,0.0,0.0,061114,0068,00,4000,00,999,149,9594
VTS,01,0097,9739965515,SP,GP,33,060113,V,0000.0000,N,00000.0000,E,0.0,0.0,061114,0068,00,4000,00,999,152,B927
```

using string function i tried to convert it into a unix date format  now i am getting time like `2014-11-06 06:01:13` its in UTC format how to convert it into IST is there any inbuild functions available to do this?

```
A = LOAD '/user/hue/Anas' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A {
             splitRow = TOKENIZE(line,'+++');
             GENERATE FLATTEN(splitRow) AS newList;
          }
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(newList,',',23));
D = FILTER C BY $1==01;
E = foreach D generate $7 as time,$15 as date;
F = foreach E generate SUBSTRING(time,0,2) as hh,SUBSTRING(time,2,4) as mm,SUBSTRING(time,4,6) as ss,SUBSTRING(date,0,2) as date,SUBSTRING(date,2,4) as month,SUBSTRING(date,4,6) as year;
G = foreach F generate CONCAT('20',CONCAT(year,CONCAT('-',CONCAT(month,CONCAT('-',date))))) as date,CONCAT(hh,CONCAT(':',CONCAT(mm,CONCAT(':',ss)))) as time;
H = FOREACH G GENERATE CONCAT(date,CONCAT(' ',time)) AS UTC;
DUMP H;
```

Comment: 1) Use Concat as CONCAT - All Caps, 2) Check if you can use inbuilt ToDate UDF to achieve  your results, 3) You can also check other third party libs for similar UDF

Comment: This discussion might be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140126/pig-3rd-party-udf-clarification

Comment: @AnasA and one other option is writing your own UDF which will do your conversion

Comment: @Anas, Posted the solution to convert UTC to IST time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the below 3 lines to your existing code, it will work

```
I = FOREACH H GENERATE ToDate(UTC,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss','UTC') AS UTCTime;
J = FOREACH I GENERATE ToDate(ToString(UTCTime,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ','Asia/Kolkata') AS ISTTime;
DUMP J
```

**Output of UTC time:**

```
(2014-11-06 06:00:37)
(2014-11-06 06:01:13)
```

**Output of IST time:**

```
(2014-11-06T11:30:37.000+05:30)
(2014-11-06T11:31:13.000+05:30)
```

This **ISTTime** is in datetime object, now you can use all the build-in functions (GetDay(),GetTime() etc).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using piggybank?

I think that the format function will do a lot of what you want.

https://gist.github.com/griggheo/1780912

You will probably have to write your own UDF for the IST conversion but that can be done inline with python or ruby or ....