# Is it ok to compare string-formatted datetimes or should I convert them to datetime objects?

Tags: python

I feel like this has probably been asked before and I apologize if it has. I couldn't find the answer.

I need to compare 2 datetimes and currently have them formatted as strings. The below seems to give the correct answers but I was wondering if there are any edge cases where it may not work. In other words, can I get by without formatting them to datetime objects? (Note: I don't need to get the difference or anything I just need to know if "a" is greater than, less than, or equal to another string).

```
a = '2013-10-25 16:01:02'

print a < '2013-10-25 14:16:39' # False
print a > '2013-10-25 14:16:39' # True
print a > '2013-10-26' # False
print a > '2012-10-26' # True
```

Comment: I see no reason to convert to a `datetime` object. It seems that would just add needless overhead of literally all you're doing is sorting

Comment: you're okay comparing them lexicographically because `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` happens to order all of the units in descending order.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Just wanted to check w/ the experts here before I put it into production.

Comment: Be careful with dates around DST changes.

Comment: @BartPlatak: Why? Will it specifically mess-up the string comparison?

Comment: while it should be ok ... it seems a little sketchy ... were you having performance problems when you converted them to datetimes?

Comment: No performance problems but I started converting them then wondered why should I add needless code

Comment: I would probably just convert them to an absolute standard of `datetime` or `time.time` ... you can do this very easily with `python-dateutil` ... but thats more just for peace of mind than anything ... it seems like you could just compare them and sort on the strings ... but it would make me nervous ...

Comment: @roippi Am I missing something here...? See my answer.

Comment: @Decency yes, you changed formats.  see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your own 'date format' with your strings are maintained like you have now (yyyy-mm-dd, etc) then it should be ok.

But for a bit more peace of mind/future proofing, I wouldn't be using strings for dates.

Answer (score 5):

Provided you *always* use two digits for months, days, hours, etc, you're using an ISO 8601 date format, and this answer applies:  [Sort ISO 8601 dates forward or backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576860/sort-iso-iso-8601-dates-forward-or-backwards).

Leading zeroes (when needed) to fill each field to its natural width are required for the guarantee to hold.  You can lose if, e.g., you use "3" instead "03" in some field:

```
a = '2013-10-25 16:01:02' # good
a = '2013-10-25 16:1:02'  # bad
a = '2013-10-25 16:01:2'  # bad
a = '2013-10-25 16:1:2'   # bad
```

You can also lose if you have negative years, but let's hope that one is just academic ;-)

It's unclear what you *want* to happen when comparing a date with a time to a date without a time.  If you don't want, e.g, `'2013-10-25' < '2013-10-25 00:00:00'` to be true, then you're out of luck with this.

If you always use a `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` representation, then alphabetic comparison is always the same as chronological comparison - up to the year 10000.  Then you're in trouble again.  But I won't be around to chide you then ;-)