# DynamoDB “OR” conditional Range query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Let's assume my table looks like:

```
Code    |StartDate  |EndDate    |Additional Attributes...

ABC     |11-24-2015 |11-26-2015 | ....

ABC     |12-12-2015 |12-15-2015 | ....

ABC     |10-05-2015 |10-10-2015 | ....

PQR     |03-24-2015 |03-27-2015 | ....

PQR     |05-04-2015 |05-08-2015 | ....
```

Provided a Code (c) and a date range (x, y), I need to be able to query items something like:

```
Query => (Code = c) AND ((StartDate BETWEEN x AND y) OR (EndDate BETWEEN x AND y))
```

I was planning to use a Primary Key as a Hash and Range Key (Code, StartDate) with an additional LSI (EndDate) and do a query on it.
I am not sure if there is a way to achieve this. I don't want to use the `SCAN` operation as it seems to scan the entire table which could be very costly.

Also, would like to achieve this in a single query.

Comment: Are your dates stored in that format? `05-04-2015 `? There are much better ways to [store unambiguous dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576860/sort-iso-iso-8601-dates-forward-or-backwards), as `05-04-2015` can be interpreted as `May 04th 2015` or `April 5th 2015`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to do this using `QUERY` and a `FilterExpression`. No need to define the `LSI` on this case. You would have to query by `Hash Key` with the `EQ` operator and then narrow the results with the Filter Expression. Here is an example with the Java SDK:

```
Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);

Map<String, Object> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
expressionAttributeValues.put(":x", "11-24-2015");
expressionAttributeValues.put(":y", "11-26-2015");

QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
    .withHashKey("Code", "CodeValueHere")
    .withFilterExpression("(StartDate between :x and :y) or (EndDate between :x and :y)")
    .withValueMap(expressionAttributeValues);


ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);

Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next().toJSONPretty());
}
```

See [Specifying Conditions with Condition Expressions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html) for more details.

Additionally, although the previous query only uses the `Hash Key` ,  you can still group the records with the `Range Key` containing the dates in the following format:

StartDate#EndDate

Table Structure:

```
Code    DateRange             |StartDate  |EndDate        
ABC     11-24-2015#11-26-2015 |11-24-2015 |11-26-2015  

ABC     12-12-2015#12-15-2015 |12-12-2015 |12-15-2015

ABC     10-05-2015#10-10-2015 |10-05-2015 |10-10-2015

PQR     03-24-2015#03-27-2015 |03-24-2015 |03-27-2015

PQR     05-04-2015#05-08-2015 |05-04-2015 |05-08-2015
```

This way If you happen to query only by `Hash Key` you would still get the records sorted by the dates. Also, I believe it is a good idea to follow the advice given about the unambiguous date format.nu

Comment: I feel this would be a perf issue if the cardinality of hashkey is low. As it fetches all the records with that hash key and later runs a filter to remove the records. Do you know what is the impact on the CapacityUnits consumed for such reads. Will there be any improvement in query perf to add two global indexes. (startdate and enddate). Or it will go through all records fetched on the hash key.

Comment: Creating the index would not cause any performance improvement as the filter is applied to the query result set. The consumed capacity units are calculated based on the query not the filtered result (meaning that the closest your initial query get to the desired end result the less wasted resources). A hash key with low cardinality will be an issue to whatever implementation, solve that issue first and everything you benefit from it. Good luck.