# JavaScript Sort Function with Descending Dates and Ascending Times

Tags: javascript, sorting

Given this data, my sort function will sort by ascending date, ascending time, and in alphabetical order by first name:

```
[
  ['Kurt Asdf', '25 Nov 2017 4:30 PM'],
  ['Vincent Qwerty', '25 Nov 2017 4:30 PM'],
  ['Zed Jones', '24 Nov 2017 2:00 PM'],
  ['Jack Mo', '25 Nov 2017 5:00 PM'],
  ['John Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],
  ['Bob Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM']
]
```

Here is the output from my current sort function (code below):

```
[
  ['Zed Jones', '24 Nov 2017 2:00 PM'],
  ['Bob Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],
  ['John Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],
  ['Kurt Asdf', '25 Nov 2017 4:30 PM'],
  ['Vincent Qwerty', '25 Nov 2017 4:30 PM'],
  ['Jack Mo', '25 Nov 2017 5:00 PM']
]
```

Here is my desired output:

```
[
  ['Bob Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],
  ['John Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],
  ['Kurt Asdf', '25 Nov 2017 4:30 PM'],
  ['Vincent Qwerty', '25 Nov 2017 4:30 PM'],
  ['Jack Mo', '25 Nov 2017 5:00 PM'],
  ['Zed Jones', '24 Nov 2017 2:00 PM']
]
```

Notice how in the above output the dates are in descending order yet the times are in ascending order and the alphabetical order within each time slot is maintained.

Here is what I have tried:

```
function sortTable(data) {
  return data.sort((elem1, elem2) => {
    var dateA         = new Date(elem1[1])
      , dateB         = new Date(elem2[1])
      , nameA         = elem1[0]
      , nameB         = elem2[0]
      , datecomp      = dateB-dateA;

    if (nameA === undefined || nameB === undefined)
      namecomp = 0;
    else
      namecomp = nameA[0] > nameB[0] || -(nameA[0] < nameB[0]);

    return datecomp > 0 ? datecomp : datecomp + namecomp;
  });
}
```

Comment: Well you'll have to separate date and time first of all, and them compare time as well after you found that dates are equal. Can't see how your code is supposed to work btw.; what is `elem1[5]` when the elements you are passing in seem to be arrays with _two_ entries?

Comment: Ascending of Date , or Descending , whatever you wanna do just fix one parameter, Time , Date and name are related , So one parameter should be specify , you can not do ascending or descending on all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a chained approach for sorting parts in different sort order.

I suggest to use a single function for comparing and returning the order.

You could use an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string for sorting date descending and time ascending. Later sort by name ascending.

> **Why taking an ISO 8601 date/time string?**
>
> The conversion of
>
> ```
> 25 Nov 2017 4:30 PM
> ```
>
> returns a sortable string in the format of
>
> ```
> 2017-11-25T15:30:00.000Z ISO in GMT
> ^^^^^^^^^^               date
>            ^^^^^^^^      time without milli seconds
> ```
>
> From this we take the date part for sorting descending
>
> ```
> 2017-11-25
> ```
>
> and the time part
>
> ```
> 15:30:00
> ```
>
> for sorting ascending, if the date is the same.
>
> More to read here: [Sort ISO 8601 dates forward or backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576860/sort-iso-8601-dates-forward-or-backwards).

```js
var array = [['Kurt Asdf', '25 Nov 2017 4:30 PM'], ['Vincent Qwerty', '25 Nov 2017 4:30 PM'], ['Zed Jones', '24 Nov 2017 2:00 PM'], ['Jack Mo', '25 Nov 2017 5:00 PM'], ['John Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'], ['Bob Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM']];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    function compare(a, b) {
        return a > b || -(a < b);
    }

    var aISO = new Date(a[1]).toISOString(),
        bISO = new Date(b[1]).toISOString();

    return compare(bISO.slice(0, 10), aISO.slice(0, 10))   // date desc
        || compare(aISO.slice(11, 19), bISO.slice(11, 19)) // time asc
        || compare(a[0], b[0]);                            // name asc
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help this works well. How would you handle the case if either of the letters of the first names are undefined? I was thinking that the compare(a[0], b[0]) would simply be skipped. Is this a good approach? Thanks again!

Comment: you could take a default value, like `compare(a[0] || '', b[0] || '')`

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion to keep things readable is to split the date into day and time in order to compare them separately :

```
// number of milliseconds in a day = 24 * 3600 * 1000 = 24 * 36e5
millis = date.getTime()
time = millis % (24 * 36e5)
day = millis - time
```

JavaScript dates precision is in milliseconds, thus, `date.getTime()` gives the number of elapsed milliseconds since 1970-01-01. Here is what I would do :

```js
var dates = [
  new Date(2017, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  new Date(2017, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2),
  new Date(2017, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1),
  new Date(2017, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1),
  new Date(2017, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2),
  new Date(2017, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2)
];

dates.sort(function (date1, date2) {
  var millisInADay = 24 * 36e5;
  var millis1 = date1.getTime();
  var millis2 = date2.getTime();
  var time1 = millis1 % millisInADay;
  var time2 = millis2 % millisInADay;
  var day1 = millis1 - time1;
  var day2 = millis2 - time2;
  if (day1 < day2) return 1;
  if (day1 > day2) return -1;
  if (time1 > time2) return 1;
  if (time1 < time2) return -1;
  return 0;
});

dates.forEach(function (date) {
  console.log(date.toLocaleString());
});
```

Here is the result using your own data table :

```js
var table = [
  ['Kurt Asdf', '25 Nov 2017 4:30 PM'],
  ['Vincent Qwerty', '25 Nov 2017 4:30 PM'],
  ['Zed Jones', '24 Nov 2017 2:00 PM'],
  ['Jack Mo', '25 Nov 2017 5:00 PM'],
  ['John Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM'],
  ['Bob Phil', '25 Nov 2017 4:00 PM']
];

table.sort(function (x1, x2) {
  var millisInADay = 24 * 36e5;
  var name1 = x1[0];
  var name2 = x2[0];
  var date1 = new Date(x1[1]);
  var date2 = new Date(x2[1]);
  var millis1 = date1.getTime();
  var millis2 = date2.getTime();
  var time1 = millis1 % millisInADay;
  var time2 = millis2 % millisInADay;
  var day1 = millis1 - time1;
  var day2 = millis2 - time2;
  if (day1 < day2) return 1;
  if (day1 > day2) return -1;
  if (time1 > time2) return 1;
  if (time1 < time2) return -1;
  if (name1 > name2) return 1;
  if (name1 < name2) return -1;
  return 0;
});

table.forEach(function (x) {
  var date = new Date(x[1]);
  console.log(date.toLocaleString(), "|", x[0]);
});
```